# Related To Polynomial Division

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

How to prove the following result

Show how a polynomial with odd number of term will never be divisible by a divisor with $x+1$ as factor for modulo $2$ arithmetic.

I don't have any idea.

Comment: So we want to show that deg$(f(x))\equiv 1\pmod2$ implies $(x+1)\nmid f(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$?

Comment: Not my strength, but if I understand the question, would it work to substitute $x=1$?

Comment: @user47805: That is clearly wrong. Take $f(x)=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modulo 2 arithmetic (that is in $\rm{GF}(2)$) any polynomial will be of the form $x^{a_1} + ... + x^{a^k}$, since we omit the terms with zero coefficient.

Saying that $x+1$ cannot be a factor of $x^{a_1} + ... + x^{a^k}$ is the same as saying that $-1$ (which is equal to $1$) is not a root of $x^{a_1} + ... + x^{a^k}.$  Obviously in $\rm{GF}(2)$ $1$ is a root of $x^{a_1} + ... + x^{a^k}$ if and only if $k$ is even.

Read more about $\rm{GF}(2)$ here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2)